# Ajax request gets 500 (Internal Server Error) on cordova

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, cordova

I have an ajax request, when I make the request in the browser it works fine, when i make it inside cordova apk, I get internal error, 
I've look into both headers, the only diference is in the ORIGIN;

This is the one not working, with origin:file://

POST http://XXX:50000/RESTAdapter/s4p/mobile/login 500 (Internal Server Error)

`Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:59
Content-Type:application/json
Cookie:saplb_*=(J2EE9465620)9465650
Host:-------
Origin:file://
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; Android SDK built for x86 Build/NYC; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/51.0.2704.90 Mobile Safari/537.36
X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id:364FC1A3-AE91-465B-821A-9EA13D731E5E
X-Requested-With:io.cordova.hellocordova`

Comment: A 500 error means something is failing on your *server*.

Comment: They say, the request dosn't have a payload, but it's working fine outside android

Comment: Have you checked the server logs? That's where the error is actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX request arrives to the server and you get an error there, on your server. Due to the error, the response is a [500](https://www.lifewire.com/500-internal-server-error-explained-2622938). If you know that this works in some cases and does not work in other cases, then check the differences between the different requests and see what is the stack trace of the error. When you have done that, you will know what the problem is. And from there on, you will be in an infinitely better position than now to fix the issue.

Comment: I'm using the same request in a local node server, that works, but when I use it on the cordova app, I get the respose 500;

Comment: @DiogoFernandes what did you see in the error logs of the server? This is crucial information which we need in order to help you.